# CC.NET Email publisher

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, email-publisher

I configured the Email publisher for cc.net. Everything works fine. But the not receiving the emails after build for the users listed in user section of email publisher nor shows any error related to email.

I am not able to trace this.

Any resolution for this?

Regards
Yaseen D M

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the recipient's spam folders? If there are a lot of emails being sent they may be false positives.